# Bash: wait for a fix number of process

Tags: bash, background-process, jobs

I wrote a bash script that executes a Java jar for a *n* number of times.

In practice, I defined e *foo()* function, containing the invocation of the *jar*, and then I run this script:

```
for RUN in $(seq 1 $RUNS) 
do 
    foo & 
done
```

Now, I would like to not execute *runs* times in parallel the *jar*.
There is a wait to limit the number of parallel execution (like a `wait` every 10 process for instance)?

Answer (score 5):

`bash` version 4.4 introduced  a useful new idiom called *parameter transformation* that can help you out in this case. In the code snippet below, note the use of `${num_jobs@P}`. The `@P` is a type of *parameter transformation* that causes the variable to be expanded as if it were a `bash` prompt string. See `man bash` for other *parameter transformation* options.

```
#!/bin/bash
num_procs=$1
num_iters=$2
num_jobs="\j"  # The prompt escape for number of jobs currently running
for ((i=0; i<num_iters; i++)); do
  while (( ${num_jobs@P} >= num_procs )); do
    wait -n
  done
  foo &
done
```

Credits to chepner at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38775799/6631810.

---

Following Kusalananda's comment, if needed, in order to make this group of processes independent of any other background jobs that would affect counting, you can wrap them with their own shell. For this a few changes are needed.

```
#!/bin/bash
# start a wrapper shell for the group of jobs
cat<<EOS | bash &
num_procs="$1"
num_iters="$2"
for ((i=0; i<num_iters; i++)); do
  # escape what's not supposed to be expanded
  # at the time of here-doc redirection
  while (( \${num_jobs@P} >= num_procs )); do  
    wait -n
  done
  foo &
done
EOS
# now you can do other things
```

Comment: Neat, but requires that the only background jobs in the script are actually those that we'd like to count (which may not be an issue).

Comment: @Kusalananda I've added a wrapper. Please take a look. Will it do?

Answer (score 3):

```
for RUN in $(seq 1 $RUNS); do
    foo &

    if (( (RUN % 10) == 0 )); then
        wait
    fi
done
```

or, with an alternative loop construct (IMHO nicer looking):

```
for (( r = 1; r <= RUNS; ++i )); do
    foo &

    if (( (r % 10) == 0 )); then
        wait
    fi
done
```

You may additionally want a lone `wait` after the loop if `$RUNS` is not a multiple of 10.

---

Instead of having `RUNS` as the total number of runs to do, one could also imagine having `n` batches of 10 jobs:

```
for (( i = 0; i < n; ++i )); do
    printf 'starting batch %d...\n' "$i"
    for (( j = 0; j < 10; ++j )); do
        foo &
    done

    echo 'waiting...'
    wait
done
```

---

Alternative solution using `xargs` and no explicit `wait`:

```
seq 1 "$RUNS" | xargs -n 1 -P 10 foo
```

This would however give the `foo` process a command line argument (one of the integers produced by `seq`) which may not be wanted. This gets rid of that issue:

```
seq 1 "$RUNS" | xargs -n 1 -P 10 sh -c 'foo'
```

Comment: To completely avoid the passing of the argument you mention by xargs, you can use the `-I` parameter to it. Check `seq 1 10 | xargs -P 10 -I# bash -c 'echo "$0"; echo "$@"'`. With `xargs -n 1 -P 10 sh -c 'foo'` it's still passed as `$0`.

Comment: @tomasz Yes, it is still passed, but to `sh` rather than to `foo`.

Comment: Ah... yes. But then `-I` helps avoid starting the wrapper shell process, right?

Comment: @tomasz Your suggestion with `-I` still starts a new shell.

Comment: It would be `xargs -P10 -I# foo` of course. Where's the shell here?

Comment: @tomasz Ah, I see.

Answer (score 2):

GNU Parallel is made for exactly this:

```
seq 1 $RUNS | parallel -j 10 -N0 foo
```

Default is to run one job per CPU core:

```
seq 1 $RUNS | parallel -N0 foo
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

For security reasons you should install GNU Parallel with your package manager, but if GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel